# Change Wordpress page URL with parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have created a dynamic content page on my Wordpress site. The content is taken from the MySQL database and will be shown based on the GET URL parameter. I created this dynamic page by inserting a PHP code to a Wordpress Page (I use Advanced Ads plugin to insert the code)

I want to change the URL without an URL parameter.

Example:

**DomainName.com/hotel-details/?hotelcode=First-Hotel**

I want to change it to

**DomainName.com/hotel-details/First-Hotel**

or

**DomainName.com/sometext/First-Hotel**

I have tried to adding mod_rewrite to the .htaccess file in the root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hotel-details/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ hotel-details/?hotelcode=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it seems doesn't work, when I access **DomainName.com/hotel-details/First-Hotel** I got an error 404 Page Not Found.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the rule the wrong way 'round. Instead try that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?hotel-details/(\w+)/$ /hotel-details/?hotelcode=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).